# Selenium webdriver click through pages of a pagination and check if an element is present

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to click through paginated pages on a website and on each page that loads I need to check if an element that was created in a previous step is present, as the assignment of pages is dynamic I don't know before its created which page the newly created element will be displayed on, so need to check all until I find it.

The code for the pagination is

```
    <div class="pagination" style="display: block; visibility: visible;"><ol><li class="current first"><a href="#">1</a></li><li><a href="#">2</a></li><li class="last"><a href="#">3</a></li></ol></div>
```

Its also possible that there will be more than 3 pages in the pagination, I realize that I need a for or while loop, but I am getting errors when I try and read the number of elements that are present.

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 1):

Use [`find_elements_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath):

```
for page_link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]/ol/li/a'):
    print "page number: %s" % page_link.text
    page_link.click()
    # parse the page and find the element
```

Another possible solution would be to get the maximum page number and iterate over the range of integers till that maximum:

```
max_page_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]/ol/li[@class="last"]/a')
max_page = int(max_page_element.text)
for page in xrange(1, max_page + 1):
    print "page number: %s" % page
    page_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]/ol/li/a[text()="%s"]' % page)
    page_link.click()
    # parse the page and find the element
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I use the above after clicking on the second page I get the follow error

Element is no longer attached to the DOM

I have seen this in the past and have been able to resolve the issue by using waits or sleeps, this does not seem to have an effect here, also when I check what is printed I only see 

page number: 1
page number: 2

Comment: @user3190832 ok, how does the pagination part look like when the error is thrown? Also, could you share a link so I can test it?

Comment: I think the issue is caused because when I click on the second page, the class is changed

**so before clicking is**

`<ol><li class="current first"><a href="#">1</a></li><li><a href="#">2</a></li><li><a href="#">3</a></li><li><a href="#">4</a></li><li><a href="#">5</a></li><li><a href="#">6</a></li><li class="last"><a href="#">7</a></li></ol>`

and after its 

`<ol><li class="first"><a href="#">1</a></li><li class="current"><a href="#">2</a></li><li><a href="#">3</a></li><li><a href="#">4</a></li><li><a href="#">5</a></li><li><a href="#">6</a></li><li class="last"><a href="#">7</a></li></ol>`

Comment: @user3190832 gotcha, I've updated the answer with the alternative solution. Give it a try.