# How do I web scrape data from several pages of search results?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I have a doubt regarding web-scraping using Xpaths and the google sheets function IMPORTXML(URL; Xpath) from an URL with several pages of search results:
The page from which I want to extract data (in particular the links of each result) is:

http://tools.morningstar.es/es/fundscreener/results.aspx?LanguageId=es-ES&Universe=FOESP%24%24ALL&Rating=0%7C0%7C1%7C1%7C1&CategoryReturn=0%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C1%7C0%7C0&AnalystRating=0%7C0%7C1%7C1%7C1%7C0%7C0&CurrencyId=EUR&URLKey=2nhcdckzon

To clarify my explanation I attach several images through links:

[Webpage elements to get (list of links)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZycN.png)

[Number of results to display, at the bottom of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLA17.png)

To obtain the links I have tried to use the following Xpath:

```
//td[@class='msDataText gridFundName Shrink']/a/@href
```

At the bottom of the page you can select the number of results to show, but selecting a different amount of results to show, or advancing page number the URL does not change.

Since the URL doesn’t change regardless of the number of results shown and the page number I only obtain the first 20 results with IMPORTXML(). These are my doubts:

1. Is there any way to extract more than just 20 links?
2. In case it is not possible to do that with google sheets, could anyone suggest an alternative?
3. Eventually, from those links (potentially 2000-3000) I want to extract approximately 30 data from each one, I have already identified their Xpaths. Could you suggest any free web-scraping tool to handle such volume of data. I am a bit lost due to the sheer number of alternatives: octoparse, kimonolabs...

I would greatly appreciate any help you could provide. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this website uses a dynamic navigation system whereby new elements are loaded upon clicking on next/previous paginated results of the table without changing URL, i.e. the content is loaded on demand by AJAX calls in the background.

Browser automation, specifically Selenium, is the general recommendation here since it allows you to scrap the data without requiring you to mimic the required AJAX calls to load the new content. Selenium can be programmed to click on the next button as often as required to fetch all pages available on the site and grab the data. Obviously, this requires some programming. I don't know what's your preference; many use Python like shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495208/selenium-webdriver-click-through-pages-of-a-pagination-and-check-if-an-element-i).